# Как заменять время каждые полчаса?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На сайте показывается статичное значение времени, например "06.07.2015 13:20". Как мне увеличивать время каждые полчаса на 30мин используя javascript или jQuery?

Comment: вариант: запомнить время периодически проверять сколько прошло, по достижении условия обновить блок

Comment: чуть-чуть подробнее можете расписать?

Comment: Не очень представляю кто будет держать страницу открытой полчаса или больше, но `setInterval(changeTimer, 30 * 60 * 1000);` будет вызывать функцию `changeTimer` раз в полчаса.

Comment: Минусик за спам.